# How to resolve HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, .net-core, http-error

I am working in .NET core 2.2 application. While calling API I got HTTP Error 404.15.

Since I am passing large no of Items in URL.

And I don't have privilege to change IIS as stated below.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" /> /* Change the Url limit here */
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also tried the following solutions, but its not working.

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(40000000)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(IFormFile file)
{

}
```

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 52428800; //50MB
    });
}
```

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null;
    //TODO: take next steps
});
```

**This is my API call**

```
https://localhost:44473/ControllerName/InsertProduct?ProductSubCategoryId="4"&ProductName="Canon EOS 200D II DSLR Camera EF-S 18 - 55 mm IS STM and 55 - 250 mm IS STM  (Black)"&ProductDescription="Is photography one of your passions? Bring home this EOS 200D II from Canon. This is Canon’s lightest DSLR that features a vari-angle LCD touch screen. It features a 24.1-megapixels APS-C CMOS sensor and a DIGIC 8 processor that capture stunning images. The EOS 200D II also has a lot of other features that make everyday photography a lot easier."&ProductSpecification="{"Specification":[{"In The Box": "1 Camera Body, 18 - 55 mm Lens, 55 - 250 mm Lens, Battery, Battery Charger, USB Cable, Camera Bag"},{"Model Number": "EOS 200D II"},{"Model Name": "eos200dii"},{"SLR Variant": "EF-S 18 - 55 mm IS STM and 55 - 250 mm IS STM"},{"Effective Pixels": "24.1 MP"},{"Image Sensor Size": "22.3 x 14.9"},{"Sensor Type": "CMOS"},{"Lens Mount": "EF Mount"},{"Shutter Speed": "1/4000 - 30 sec"},{"Image Format": "JPEG, RAW, C-RAW, RAW + JPEG, C-RAW + JPEG"},{"Video Resolution": "1920 x 1080"},{"Video Quality": "Full HD"},{"Battery Type": "Lithium"},{"Weight": "654g"}]}"&ProductOptions="{"Options":[{"Bank Offer":"10% Instant discount with HDFC Bank PayZapp Card on purchase of Rs.300 or more"},{"No Cost EMI": "Avail No Cost EMI on select cards for orders above ?3000"},{"Partner Offers":"Get FLAT 5% BACK with Amazon Pay ICICI Bank Credit card card for Prime members. Flat 3% BACK for non-Prime members. No minimum order value. No upper limit on cashback."}]}"&ProductPrice="57499"&ProductBrand="Canon"&IsActive="True"&Quantity="50"&ImageURL="NULL"
```

**Calling Method in Controller**

```
public int InsertProduct(Product product)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> keyValues = this.GetProperty<Product>(product);

    int i = bl.AddProduct<Product>(keyValues);
    return i;
}
```

**So Anyone can suggest me a better Idea to resolve this issue.**

Comment: Please show us how you are trying to call the endpoint, and the entire action you aretrying to call

Comment: Yahh I will edit my question.

Comment: And where are you calling that from? just in the address bar, or from some code?

Comment: Wait a minute.... The api call is showing a GET request not POST request..... Yet your UploadFiles is using POST... So why dont you try to use POST instead? Also I am confused where is the error in the UploadFile or the InsertProduct call.... Please show the relevant code

Comment: I figured it out. Please look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to call InsertProduct using POST... That way the query string limit does NOT apply.

Your action in your controller should look Like this:

```
[HttpPost]//this is to accept a POST rather than a GET
public int InsertProduct([FromBody]Product product)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> keyValues = this.GetProperty<Product>(product);

    int i = bl.AddProduct<Product>(keyValues);
    return i;
}
```

Notice also that I added **[FromBody]** to the Product parameter.
That way the controller will expect the json to be inside the body of the request and NOT in the url, nor from the form collection.

Also you will need to change the api call to use POST and not GET.
Because you did NOT show the code that makes the API call.... I cannot help you change that to use POST..

If you post the code that makes the API call I will update this answer to show you how to use POST.

**Final Notes:**
MaxRequestBodySize  had NOTHING to do with your problem so changing it is meaningless...

The limit set is for the **Query String** and the **Url** NOT the **Body** of the request...

Just look at this line in your config file:

```
<requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" /> /* Change the Url limit here */
```

You see **maxQueryString** and **maxUrl** both of those affect the URL size NOT the body of the request.

Body is what is inside the request during a POST or PUT...

As a matter of fact GET request have NO body... and if they do the server IGNORES it.

So by sending the data in a POST you will not be affected by that limit.

Comment: I don't have config file, I have only app.settings.json file.

Comment: @ahamed you posted an xml file.... appsettings is a JSON file... so something is wrong with your configuration.  you see this line is NOT JSON: <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" /> /* Change the Url limit here */

Comment: @ahamed I am pretty sure that XML YOU posted comes from a config file.

Comment: @ahamed by the way my answer is correct.  The way to fix it is by following what I stated in it.

Comment: My version is 2.2. Yahh it is not a XML  file. Why I mentioned appsettings is, I don't have config file.

Comment: @ahamed I do not understand.... Where does the XML you posted come from? Where is this code: <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="1000" />?